# How to mock file payloads in HttpServletRequest without a framework?

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, httprequest

I've written a servlet to upload files to the server via [`HttpServletRequest`](http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=winstone%2Fsrc%2Fjava%2Fjavax%2Fservlet%2Fhttp%2FHttpServletRequest.java) and I need to test it. Unfortunately the framework at work isn't allowing mocking frameworks, so I need to write my own mock of `HttpServletRequest` for JUnit tests.

I'm using some Apache Commons classes we have available to get files from the request:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

private static List<FileItem> getFilesFromReq(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    final ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

    List<FileItem> fileItems = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileItems;
}
```

I've written an implementation of `HttpServletRequest` as the mock (actually an extension of a partial mock someone else in the company wrote). But I can't figure out how to add to the request body, let alone how to include files as `multipart/form-data`. And there don't seem to be any methods in `HttpServletRequest` even referencing the request body.

I found online the source code of [`DiskFileItemFactory`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItemFactory.html)/[`FileItemFactory`](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/org/apache/commons/fileupload/fileitemfactory-c7a7e.html) and [`ServletFileUpload`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html), but how it works and how the files are included in the request is still rather opaque to me.

Can anyone give me some guidance for adding files to `multipart/form-data` in a mock `HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: You should only test your logic you've added. You are currently trying to test  things you don't own. What kind of test would you like to write? If it's a unit test , then I would suggest injecting ServletFileUpload as a dependency into your class under test. This will make it easier to test and you can focus on testing your own logic instead of 3rd party libraries.

Comment: @StevenDiamante, thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm trying to test the logic of what I've written, which includes the method I wrote above. (And I'm already trying to avoid libraries.) What do you mean about injecting ServletFileUpload as a dependency? How would I do that? Would you like to write a full answer, or at least post a link to a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend making this method non-static first of all. Next, instead of instantiating the ServletFileUpload instance in the method it should be injected in the constructor of your class.

```
class FileUploader { 
private final ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload;

FileUploader(ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload) {
  this.servletFileUpload = servletFileUpload;
}

}
```

Now in your test you can pass in a mock of ServletFileUpload. You can use Mockito or JMock or create your own mock class. After doing this you'll be able to verify that the your mocked class's method parseRequest was called.

Comment: Thanks! That explains what you meant by dependency injection, which is helpful. Unfortunately I can't use a mocking framework: "Unfortunately the framework at work isn't allowing mocking frameworks."

Comment: So you'll need to Subclass and override the parseRequest method. So make a class that extends ServletFileUpload. Then override the parseRequest method. You can have it return a list of FileItems you build yourself. Then assert the output.